# Problems with DNS in NodeMCU

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I am trying to just make a connection from the ESP8266 and a test server like www.httpbin.org to get some data. I keep having problems in the connection.
I am using a very simple code that (excluding the obvious connection to the local WiFi) looks like:

```
net.dns.setdnsserver("8.8.8.8",1)
net.dns.resolve("httpbin.org", function(server_ip)
    if (server_ip == nil) then print("DNS fail!") else

        print(server_ip)

        conn=net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)

        conn:on("receive", function(conn, payload) 
                        print('\nReceived\n')
                        print(payload)
                        end )

        conn:on("connection", function(conn, payload) 
                        print('\nConnected') 
                        conn:send("HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                        .."Host: httpbin.org/get\r\n"
                        .."Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
                        .."Accept: */*\r\n\r\n")
                       end) 

        conn:connect(80, server_ip)

        end
    end)
```

I get as result that the print(server_ip) returns

```
userdata: 3fff1b80
```

And the connection hangs (I never get any message printed). What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Do you need any more feedback? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there. Try this:

```
net.dns.setdnsserver("8.8.8.8", 1)
net.dns.resolve("httpbin.org", function(sk, server_ip)
    if (server_ip == nil) then print("DNS fail!") else

        print(server_ip)

        conn = net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)

        conn:on("receive", function(conn, payload)
            print("Received: " .. payload)
        end)

        conn:on("connection", function(conn, payload)
            print("Connected")
            conn:send("GET /get HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                    .. "Host: httpbin.org\r\n"
                    .. "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
                    .. "Accept: */*\r\n\r\n")
        end)

        conn:connect(80, server_ip)
    end
end)
```

I changed two things:

- as per the [docs](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/net/#netdnsresolve) the callback for `net.dns.resolve` has *2* parameters (socket and IP address)
- the HTTP headers were wrong:

  - `host` really is just the host
  - but the HTTP verb and the path were missing, it's `GET /get HTTP/1.1`

Of course you may just as well strip this down to:

```
conn = net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)

conn:on("receive", function(conn, payload)
    print("Received: " .. payload)
end)

conn:on("connection", function(conn, payload)
    print("Connected")
    conn:send("GET /get HTTP/1.1\r\n"
            .. "Host: httpbin.org\r\n"
            .. "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
            .. "Accept: */*\r\n\r\n")
end)

conn:connect(80, "httpbin.org")
```